# Сломалась авторизация на github через pycharm

Tags: github, pycharm

Впервые столкнулся с проблемой.

`Pycharm 2019.2.4, Windows 7`

При обращении к `VCS` -> `Import into version control` -> `Share project`...
и авторизации по логин\пароль, выдает:

```
Incorrect credentials. Request response: 401 Unauthorized
```

пара валидная, потому что через браузер войди получается.

UPD: вернулся на рабочие версии IDE, без изменений, так же самая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD2: подведу небольшое резюме по вопросу. стандартными средствами залогиниться так и не удалось. сработало следующее костыльное решение: клонирую свой репозиторий с gitbub на компьютер. вношу изменения, сохраняю, комичу и пушу. запрос на логин и пароль проходят успешно. если создавать проект с нуля на компьютере, то расшарить его на github так же невозможно. обойти этот казус получилось созданием репозитория в браузере, дальше клонирование и по схеме выше. Есть ли смысл создавать это костыльное решение как ответ, не уверен.

Comment: Видимо в браузере используется другая пара логин/пароль.

Comment: первым делом проверил. затем, сменил на новый пароль, для верности. не помогло

Comment: А раньше работало?

Comment: раньше был на win 10 и пичарм 2020, и работало все "из коробки".

Comment: вернулся на win 10 и pycharm 2020, та же самая проблема.

Comment: А вы не пробовали автоматизироваться по RSA ключу а не по логин/пароль? Или по токину.

Comment: @Hellseher нет. меня устраивал имеющийся функционал. единожды указав пару, больше об этом не вспоминать.

Answer (score 2):

Сталкивался с похожей проблемой после смены пароля в GitLab. Возможно для GitHub тоже подойдет.

Вылечил следующим образом:

1. Win + R, вводим `control /name Microsoft.CredentialManager`.
2. Переходим на вкладку "Учетные данные Windows".
3. Удаляем сохраненные пароли для Git.

Решение для Windows 10.

Помог в решении похожий [вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication/52092795#52092795).

Comment: благодарю за ответ.  На сейчас, получился какой-то костыль. Загрузил со своего репозитория проект. внес изменения, закоммитил,  и пуш прошел.

Comment: воспользовался Вашей рекомендацией. у меня вкладка "учетные данные Windows" девственно пуста.